# Implicit wait and explicit wait in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

if we give implicit wait 30 second and explicit wait 7 second for webelement then assume element not show or anything,then how much time it take for throw exception?

I just want to know how much time take to throw exception? & it will execute both code or just one code? if one code will execute then which one & which code ignore? and why?

Comment: It will took 37 seconds. Implicit wait will wait for the fixed time you set (as 30 seconds). Explicit wait will wait for an condition satisfied in a specific time, in your case it will wait for maximum 7 seconds.

Comment: This won't be predictable as you'll have competing polling loops.  The answer is never mix implicit and explicit waits.  The question also doesn't specify where the exception is thrown.  Each polling loop round will ignore a thrown exception.... but it's still thrown there.  So the first exception of any type would be thrown almost immediately if the polling loops weren't conflicting with each other's .5 second sleeps per iteration.